# IntelliSense for Python projects in Visual Studio Express 2013 with PTVS

Tags: python, visual-studio, intellisense, ptvs

I have a simple testproject structured as follows:

```
testproject
|
|-subpackage
|  |
|  |- __init__.py
|  |- subpackagetest.py
|
|- __init__.py
|- test.py
```

Both `__init__.py` files are empty. `test.py` contains

```
from testproject.subpackage.subpackagetest import Subpackagetestclass

class Projectclass(object):
    pass
```

and `subpackagetest.py` contains

```
from testproject.test import Projectclass

class Subpackagetestclass(object):
    pass
```

When hovering over any of the imported classes or packages Visual Studio only shows `<unknown type>`.

How can I make IntelliSense recognize my own packages, modules and classes?

Comment: Where does your project file live? Remember that it won't treat the project folder itself as a package (i.e. if you want `testproject` to be a package, then the project file should be alongside it, not inside it).

Comment: The project file is alongside it. I just discovered that when I create new files and classes, IntelliSense is available until I restart VisualStudio - so it seems this could be a bug, not a "normal problem".

Comment: Can you please file a bug at https://github.com/Microsoft/ptvs ?

Comment: I did: https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/812